# Memory Model: What is the difference between `store(x, relaxed); atomic::fence(seq_cst);` and `store(x, seq_cst)`

Tags: c++, rust, memory-model

I see a code snippet in rust `crossbeam-epoch` library

```rust
pub(crate) fn pin(&self) -> Guard {
...
   self.epoch.store(new_epoch, Ordering::Relaxed);
   atomic::fence(Ordering::SeqCst);
...
```

I am curious that

- why not just `self.epoch.store(new_epoch, Ordering::SeqCst);`?
- Do they provide a same memory ordering guarantee?
- Is there any performance difference between these two approach?

(Maybe) Equivalent C++ code:

```cpp
epoch.store(new_epoch, std::memory_order_relaxed);
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

v.s.

```
epoch.store(new_epoch, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

Comment: Why is the tag C++ spammed here?

Comment: @273K because the memory models between c++ and rust are very similar lol

Comment: @Yriuns *"because the memory models between c++ and rust are very similar"* -- But not the same? And not the same code. And you are asking about a rather technical detail, something that could very well be the reason why the models are not the same.

Comment: @JaMiT C++11 first define a memory model in language and rust inherits it. I don't see a misleading of my tags.

Comment: "[Rust atomics currently follow the same rules as C++20 atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/index.html)". So the intention is sound, but a c++ tag will attract answerers who don't know Rust, so maybe you can re-add the tag together with some equivalent C++ code?

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure about the code, but doesn't this mean the compiler may chose to reorder the store with some preceding operations? I don't see anything in the [actual code](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-epoch/0.9.15/src/crossbeam_epoch/internal.rs.html#425-426) that would benefit from that, though.)

Comment: @Caesar Thank you for your opinion and great advice! I have add the c++ code and re-add the tag. Also I noticed that there is a comment in crossbeam: It is not
clear that this is permitted by the C++ memory model (SC fences work very differently from SC accesses). I'm going to dig with it.

Comment: *"I don't see a misleading of my tags."* -- It's not a question of misleading, but of keeping the question focused, so that there is a good reason to think there is just one question to be answered, rather than one per language tag.

Comment: @JaMiT The question is memory model as the title said. Rust or C++ is just a implementation, right?

Comment: Fences can be used to order several operations in some thread A with other operations on thread B, where the order of operations within a thread doesn't matter, but the order of modifications that, say, thread A performs must all be visible from thread B. This looks like the "release" fence (because the store is sequenced-before it), maybe the "acquire" fence has multiple operations sequenced-after it? It also looks like in Rust, atomic operations can only synchronize-with fences when they have release or acquire ordering, not seqcst, that mayb be another factor.

Comment: It would be interesting to inspect code around call sites of the function. That code may contain more atomic loads and stores, all intentionally allowed to be reordered by the compiler and/or by the processor + memory controller, including reordering of the `new_epoch` store before “preceding” stores or vice versa. (The fence prevents loads/stores before and after from “leaking through”.) Tagging the `new_epoch` store directly as `SeqCst` would reduce this “reordering flexibilty” by a tiny bit, which _might_ affect efficiency, e.g. on platforms like SPARC, which has ~15 memory barrier types.

Comment: @isaactfa: Is that a difference from C++?  In C++, `seq_cst` includes all the semantics of `acquire` and/or `release` as appropriate.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, it would be different from C++. I think I was wrong though. I guess I wrote it because the `fence` docs only say "Atomic operations with `Release` or `Acquire` semantics can also synchronize with a fence", where `Release` and `Acquire` link to the respective ordering, but the word "semantics" indicates that the stricter orderings would work too. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

They have different semantics for how they can be reordered with other loads and stores in this thread.

```
epoch.store(new_epoch, std::memory_order_relaxed);
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

The `seq_cst` fence acts as a full barrier; no loads or stores can be reordered across it.  However, nothing here prevents the store to `epoch` from being reordered with *earlier* loads or stores.  (Provided that the ordering on those loads and stores also allows it; i.e. the store to `epoch` can be reordered with earlier `relaxed` loads, and all earlier stores regardless of their specified ordering.)

```
epoch.store(new_epoch, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

A `seq_cst` store is not reordered with other `seq_cst` loads and stores.  However, for purposes of reordering with non-`seq_cst` accesses, it is treated as if it were simply `release`.  It will not be reordered with *earlier* loads or stores, but nothing here prevents it from being reordered with *later* loads and stores.  (Specifically, `relaxed` or `acquire` loads, or `relaxed` stores.)

To be concrete, consider the following code.

```c++
std::atomic<bool> a{false}, x{false}, b{false};

void v1() {
    a.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    b.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void v2() {
    a.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    b.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void reader() {
    bool bb = b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    bool xx = x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    bool aa = a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    std::cout << aa << xx << bb;
}
```

In `v1`, the store to `x` can be reordered with the store to `a`, but not with the store to `b`.  If `reader` is run in another thread, it may observe `aa == false && xx == true`, but it must not observe `xx == false && bb == true`.

In `v2`, the reverse is true: the store to `x` can be reordered with the store to `b`, but not with the store to `a`.  The `reader` function must not observe `aa == false && xx == true`, but it may observe `xx == false && bb == true`.